# Find array object by ID and return it in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I try to fetch object `vorlagen` with ID `6310` from [this](https://www.bfs.admin.ch/bfsstatic/dam/assets/14856203/master) API and want to show if property `vorlageAngenommen` is true or false.

The JSON object looks as follows:

[image: API extract]

My code that does not run, looks as follows (I am not sure if this is a good base at all):

```js
import useSWR from "swr";
import "./styles.css";

const fetcher = (...args) => fetch(...args).then((res) => res.json());

const arrayFindObjectByProp = (arr, prop, val) => {
  return arr.find((obj) => obj[prop] == val);
};

export default function App() {
  const { data, error } = useSWR(
    "https://www.bfs.admin.ch/bfsstatic/dam/assets/14856203/master",
    fetcher
  );
  const specificVoting = null;

  console.log("swr error: ", error);
  console.log("swr data: ", data);

  return (
    <div className="App">

      <div style={{backgroundColor: "red"}}>
        {data ? (
          {specificVoting = arrayFindObjectByProp(data.schweiz.vorlagen, vorlagenId, '6310')}
          <h4>{specificVoting.vorlageAngenommen}</h4>
        ) : (
          <h1>loading...</h1>
        )}
      </div>

    </div>
  );
}
```

I created a sandbox as well that can be found [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-ishizaka-f5eek).

**Any idea how I can fetch and present a specific element of an array where I know the ID?**

Many thanks for your feedback in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has a few issues.

First: You should extract the value outside of the return statement

Second; You should pass on the property value as a `string` to `arrayFindObjectByProp` function

Lastly: Since the value returned is a `boolean`, you need to convert it into a string to display in the component

```
export default function App() {
  const {data, error } = useSWR(
    "https://www.bfs.admin.ch/bfsstatic/dam/assets/14856203/master",
    fetcher
  );

  console.log("swr error: ", error);
  console.log("swr data: ", data);
  const specificVoting =
    data && arrayFindObjectByProp(data.schweiz.vorlagen, "vorlagenId", "6310");
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div style={{ backgroundColor: "red" }}>
        
        {data ? (
          <h4>{specificVoting.vorlageAngenommen.toString()}</h4>
        ) : (
          <h1>loading...</h1>
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-array-find-object-by-prop-forked-e2x6n?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Thank you Shubham for your very appreciated solution and explaining me the issues I had in my code. This helped me a lot and I am getting better :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
const fetcher = (...args) => fetch(...args).then((res) => res.json());

export default function App() {
  const { data } = useSWR(
    "https://www.bfs.admin.ch/bfsstatic/dam/assets/14856203/master",
    fetcher
  );

  const item = data?.shchweiz?.vorlagen.find(
    (item) => item.vorlagenId === 6310
  );

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div style={{ backgroundColor: "red" }}>
        {data ? (
          <>
            vorlageAngenommen value:{" "}
            {item?.vorlageAngenommen ? `true` : `false`}
          </>
        ) : (
          <h1>loading...</h1>
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-array-find-object-by-prop-forked-z8lg1?file=/src/App.js:50-673

Comment: Thank you Dennis for your help and this working solution where I additionally could learn about https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining

Answer (score 0):

it seems that

```
{specificVoting = arrayFindObjectByProp(data.schweiz.vorlagen, vorlagenId, '6310')}
```

should be replaced by followed

```
{specificVoting = arrayFindObjectByProp(data.schweiz.vorlagen, 'vorlagenId', '6310')}
```

Comment: Thank you newbie for your feedback and your hint that helped me. I had some additional issues in my code as can be seen in the other answers.

Answer (score 0):

i think its this line

```
{specificVoting = arrayFindObjectByProp(data.schweiz.vorlagen, vorlagenId, '6310')}
```

It should have been this way:

```
{specificVoting = arrayFindObjectByProp(data.schweiz.vorlagen, "vorlagenId", '6310')}
```

`"vorlagenId"` should be passed as string and not variable.

Comment: Thank you shaswat.dharaiya for your feedback and your hint that helped me. I had some additional issues in my code as can be seen in the other answers.

Comment: Please vote the answer if it was helpful.